# Modeling memory access on Z3

Tags: arrays, z3

I'm modelling a program's memory accesses using Z3 and I have a doubt about performance that I'd like to share.

I wanted to model on a compact way something like a:

```
memset(dst, 0, 1000);
```

My first try was to use the array theory, but that meant to either create a thousand terms like `(assert (and (= (select mem 0) 0) (= (select mem 1) 0) ...` or a thousand similar stores or a quantified formula:

```
(forall (x Int) (implies (and (>= x 0) (< x 1000)) (= (select mem x) 0))
```

But I was told to avoid quantifiers while using arrays.

Next idea was to define a UF:

```
 (define-fun newmemfun ((idx Int)) Int (
   ite (and (>= idx 0) (< idx 1000)) 0 (prevmemfun idx)
 ))
```

But that means that I need to define a new function for each memory write operation (even for individual store operations, not just multiple stores like memset or memcpy). Which would end up creating a very nested ITE structure that would even save "old" values for a same index. ie:

```
mem[0] = 1;
mem[0] = 2;

would be:
(ite (= idx 0) 2 (ite (= idx 0) 1 ...
```

Which is functionally correct but the size of the expression (and I guess the generated AST for it) tends to accumulate very fast and I'm not sure if Z3 is optimized to detect and handle this case.

So, the question is: what would be the most performant way to encode memory operations that can cope with large multiple stores like the example above and individual stores at the same time.

Thanks,
pablo.

PS: non-closed and non-matching parenthesis intended :P.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing a bit more about your end goal, aside from modeling memory accesses (e.g., are you going to be doing verification, test case generation, etc.?), it's somewhat hard to answer, as you have many options.  However, you may have the most flexibility to control performance issues if you rely on one of the APIs.  For example, you can define your own memory accesses as follows (link to z3py script: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/gO6i ):

```
address_bits = 7
data_bits = 8

s = Solver()

# mem is a list of length program step, of a list of length 2^address_bits of bitvectors of size 2^data_bits
mem =[]

# modify a single address addr to value at program step step
def modifyAddr(addr, value, step):
  mem.append([]) # add new step
  for i in range(0,2**address_bits):
    mem[step+1].append( BitVec('m' + str(step + 1) + '_' + str(i), data_bits) )

    if i != addr:
      s.add(mem[step+1][i] == mem[step][i])
    else:
      s.add(mem[step+1][i] == value)

# set all memory addresses to a specified value at program step step
def memSet(value, step):
  mem.append([])
  for i in range(0,2**address_bits):
    mem[step+1].append( BitVec('m' + str(step + 1) + '_' + str(i), data_bits) )
    s.add(mem[step+1][i] == value)

modaddr = 23 # example address
step = -1
# initialize all addresses to 0
memSet(0, step)
step += 1
print s.check()
for i in range(0,step+1): print s.model()[mem[i][modaddr]] # print all step values for modaddr

modifyAddr(modaddr,3,step)
step += 1
print s.check()
for i in range(0,step+1): print s.model()[mem[i][modaddr]]

modifyAddr(modaddr,4,step)
step += 1
print s.check()
for i in range(0,step+1): print s.model()[mem[i][modaddr]]

modifyAddr(modaddr,2**6,step)
step += 1
print s.check()
for i in range(0,step+1): print s.model()[mem[i][modaddr]]

memSet(1,step)
step += 1
print s.check()
for i in range(0,step+1): print s.model()[mem[i][modaddr]]

for a in range(0,2**address_bits): # set all address values to their address number
  modifyAddr(a,a,step)
  step += 1

print s.check()
print "values for modaddr at all steps"
for i in range(0,step+1): print s.model()[mem[i][modaddr]] # print all values at each step for modaddr

print "values at final step"
for i in range(0,2**address_bits): print s.model()[mem[step][i]] # print all memory addresses at final step
```

This naive implementation allows you to either (a) set all memory addresses to some value (like your memset), or (b) modify a single memory address, constraining all other addresses to have the same value.  For me, it took a few seconds to run and encoded about 128 steps of 128 addresses, so it had around 20000 bitvector expressions of 8 bits each.

Now, depending on what you are doing (e.g., do you allow atomic writes to several addresses like this memset, or do you want to model them all as individual writes?), you could add further functions, like modify a subset of addresses to some values in a program step.  This will allow you some flexibility to trade off modeling accuracy for performance (e.g., atomic writes to blocks of memory versus modifying single addresses at a time, which will run into performance problems).  Also, nothing about this implementation requires the APIs, you could encode this as an SMT-LIB file as well, but you will probably have more flexibility (e.g., lets say you want to interact with models to constrain future sat checks) if you use one of the APIs.

Comment: Hi, I find your approach interesting but unsuitable for my case. You're pretty much redoing the Array Theory store operation (every element except index "i" of the new array is equal to the previous one) but outside the solver, from the python API. This works well for relatively small address spaces (ie 7bits) but I 'm working on a symbolic execution engine for X86. So, my address space is 32bits and a single memory write step would take over 4GB of ram to process it.

You seem to agree though, that unwinding the memory operations (having a thousand asserts in my example) is the way to go.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, the modeling approach is dependent upon your end goal, so you definitely want to apply some abstraction, e.g., the atomic writes I mentioned. And yes, this is essentially the array theory, but where you have more control.  Another improvement would be to only introduce new memory locations when the data changes, and keep track of the last step of the program that modified each location. If you're going to be modeling a 32-bit address space, I imagine you'll have to lose some model accuracy for performance, as you won't be able to model everything precisely.